# Usage of uintptr_t vs DWORD_PTR

Tags: c++, types, stdint

Both are used for storing addresses and doing pointer arithmetic, both are defined in WinAPI, when should I use a `uintptr_t` (cstdint) vs a `DWORD_PTR` (Windows.h)? Both are 32bits and 64bits in x86 and x86_64 respectively

> A `DWORD_PTR` is an `unsigned long` type used for pointer precision. It is used when casting a pointer to an `unsigned long` type to perform pointer arithmetic. `DWORD_PTR` is also commonly used for general 32-bit parameters that have been extended to 64 bits in 64-bit Windows.

I do not intend for my code to be portable, I'm stuck with WinAPI.
What type is the best use case?

Comment: I never use Windows typedefs unless directly working against Windows API functions.  And even then, I end up using `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: I'd pick `uintptr_t`, if only because it doesn't SCREAM AT YOU. And for the fact that the "DWORD" is a lie in 64 bits, and code that lies to you is horrible. ("sizeof(DWORD) bytes should be enough for anyone"...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prefer [`uintptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) it is part of the C++ standard as of C++11 and later. [DWORD_PTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc230322.aspx) is specific to Visual C++ and is therefore not portable.

While Visual C++ may choose to implement `uintptr_t` as a `DWORD_PTR` or `unsigned long` under the hood, that is up to them to do, you are safer sticking to the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

`uintptr_t` (actually `std::uintptr_t` in C++) is *not* defined in WinAPI, it's defined in the standard C++ header `<cstdint>`. The standard C++ library is defined by the C++ language and has nothing to do with WinAPI.

If you want to use the type for interaction with WinAPI, use `DWORD_PTR` as that's what the WinAPI functions expect.

For other uses, it's really up to you. I prefer standard types over platform-specific ones, so I'd use `std::uintptr_t`, but either is possible.